# How to add Forgot/Reset password link in #Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I am using #AngularFire2 in my project. I want to add a **Reset / Forgot password** link in my login view.

Any ideas how this is done?

I want to #AskFirebase

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email. If you're having trouble making that work, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen  . That is perfect ! works like a charm. But I could not find that function `auth.sendPasswordResetEmail` in the `AngularFire` auth object. Is it yet to be included? I am using ` angularfire2: ^2.0.0-beta.8,`

Comment: I don't know if it's included. If not, you can simply call it on the Firebase JavaScript API.

Comment: Look [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/480).

Answer (score 0):

Just implement this two methods:

Make a request, and Firebase will send a email with the code

```
requestPasswordReset(email: string) : Promise<any> {
    return this.afAuth.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
}
```

Then you need to get this code with a new password from user

```
confirmNewPassword(code: string, password: string) : Promise<any> {
    return this.afAuth.auth.confirmPasswordReset(code, password);
}
```